# UITextField not calling editingChanged event when text is autocorrected

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with a return key type of `Done`, and I've set the delegate to resign first responder status when the return button is tapped. I've also set an `editingChanged` action to let me know when the user edits the text. But it seems like it isn't being called in the following context.

Say the user has entered "Pizzs" into the text field. The `editingChanged` action is triggered and it says the text field's value is "Pizzs". Meanwhile, "Pizza" comes up as a suggestion in the keyboard suggestion bar. If they hit the space bar, the autocorrection is accepted and the `editingChanged` event is called, with the new text "Pizza ". But if they hit `Done` then the keyboard is dismissed, the text is changed to "Pizza" in the UITextField, but `editingChanged` is never called.

This is a bug, right? Should I report it to Apple? Or is this expected behavior because the text is being changed programmatically rather than by the user? And can anyone think of a good workaround?

Comment: Hi Will,  
Did you manage to fix this issue? I have the same problem :(

Comment: No. I filed a Radar with Apple but I don't think it was ever addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.allEditingEvents` for this case.

```swift
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(_:)), for: .allEditingEvents)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and worked around it by implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool`, and doing the same thing there that I was doing in my editingChanged event handler.

So, I basically did this:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    processText()
    return false
}

@objc func textFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    processText()
}

func processText() {
    // Process text here
}
```

Comment: This only applies if the user taps return to complete the autocorrect. But tapping the screen (without cancelling the autocorrect popup) also triggers the autocorrect replacement but does not call `textFieldShouldReturn`